# How to make two fermions entangled with each other?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

How to make two fermions entangled with each other. When we say two particles have to interact with each other to get entangled, what kind of interaction is that?

Comment: I think this can help: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/25311054.pdf

Comment: In any given system with multiple parts or multiple particles, practically all states are entangled (by any conventional definition of "entangled"). Non-entangled states are exceptional. So practically any interaction of any kind will convert an initially non-entangled state into an entangled one. Only exceptional kinds of "interaction," like no interaction at all, will preserve the non-entangled condition.

Answer (score 1):

An easy example could be a linear evolution evolving each of the two fermions into a superposition of output modes. For example, if you have
$$c_a^\dagger\to \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\left(c_1^\dagger+c_2^\dagger+c_3^\dagger\right),\\
c_b^\dagger\to \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\left(c_1^\dagger+c_2^\dagger-c_3^\dagger\right),\\$$
then
$$c_a^\dagger c_b^\dagger\lvert \text{vac}\rangle \to -\frac{2}{3}\left( c_1^\dagger c_3^\dagger + c_2^\dagger c_3^\dagger  \right)\lvert \text{vac}\rangle,$$
that is,
$$\lvert a,b\rangle\to N(\lvert 1,3\rangle+\lvert 2,3\rangle),$$
which is an entangled state of the two fermions (or more precisely, an entangled state over the modes that we are considering).